# Modify username + jomsocial

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I've used Jomsocial plugin in my site.

And I found that there are only 2 options which are Real Name and Username for displaying on front page.

I am wondering how can I customize it so that I can make it display in another format.

For example, I want it display

- ***user's first name + City***
- Or user's ***first name + last name's first letter***(Tom G/Tom.G)
- or may be I can show a custom field like "***display name***" that I've asked user to fill on registration form.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link:- https://www.jomsocial.com/company/docs/administrator-guide/user-profiles/custom-profile-fields

Comment: @RaviHirani this is not what I'm looking for.... I want my custom field **display name** to be displayed as display name in all over the site.